# Spring 3.1, Aspect, Tomcat - circularity error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, aspectj

I have a pretty complex web-application where the whole DAO has been outsourced to an `@Aspect` class which will load database entities whenever methods are accessed which need those.

This whole approach is working wonderfully when the web app is launched from netbeans. However, when I try to deploy the same .war to a standalone tomcat (same version of tomcat, same version of java), I get the following exception upon startup:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Advice precedence circularity error`

**And I just can't figure out what is causing the problem and why the application runs fine when starting through netbeans.**

**Maven** config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
                <meminitial>256m</meminitial>
                <maxmem>768m</maxmem>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Spring**: 3.1.0.RELEASE:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

I honestly don't know what info I should include in this post as I don't even know where to start... Feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Comment: When you say 'the same WAR', do you mean the *same*? Or is the WAR running in NetBeans generated by NetBeans and the other by the maven-war-plugin?

Comment: Hm.. I always thought both are built using the maven-war-plugin? But one is run by pressing 'Run' in netbeans and the other one is built by maven-war-plugin

Comment: Maybe, I have not used NetBeans for a long time but depends on your run configuration. I use IntelliJ, and it does not (at least for my default setup). I suppose it'd be worth comparing the WARs, perhaps running both exploded would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: There is not much to compare - I have only one war. I don't know what netbeans does different .. maybe changing something on the tomcat? I copied my exploded directory from netbeans /target/ directory onto my server machine. Running the exploded war didn't change anything

Comment: Oh ok. So two different machines, both 64bit? And the working WAR when run via NetBeans is copied across to the server machine, dropped in the 'webapps' directory of Tomcat, Tomcat then fails to deploy it with the error above? Have you got any other exceptions (regardless of whether they are all linked) or any WARNINGs/SEVEREs logged?

Comment: Two different machines. One is Win7 64bit (where netbeans is run) the other is a Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-35squeeze2). I run via netbeans (or build - makes no difference), take the localy working .war, copy it over to the linux's tomcat's webapp dir, start the linux's tomcat and get just that error I stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a complete answer but the links should be helpful:

It sounds as if the difference here is that your machines are returning the order of declared methods, of a particular class, differently, which changes how Aspect advices are run:

> Spring uses getDeclaredMethods to determine the order of the advices,
>   but getDeclaredMethods returns methods in unspecified order. ([see more](http://zeroturnaround.com/forum/topic.php?id=779))

There is also a Spring ticket for an issue that sounds very similar to yours:
[SPR-5314](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5314)

Hope that's a little helpful. Good luck.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-58498.html - might also be a good read.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I stumbled across all these postings already - not very satisfied with my research though. The ticket is from 2008. There has to be some fixing until now I suppose. This problem can't be THAT uncommon, can it?

Comment: It indeed looks like the different JDKs cause the problems. I will get a Win7 machine tomorrow to where I can deploy - maybe this will fix things..

Comment: A little late to the party, but apparently the different JDKs was the problem :)